# Using jquery.chained.js , this.form.submit() , selectbox

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, chained

I'm a beginner with jquery and have a problem combining jquery.chained.js and getting the selectboxes attached to each other to submit when changed.

I have:

> $(document).ready(function(){
>
> $("#filter_category").chainedTo("#filter_type");
>
> });

```
<form id="filter_form" name="filter_form" method="get" action="">
<select name="filter_type" id="filter_type" onchange="this.form.submit()"> 
<select name="filter_category" id="filter_category" onchange="this.form.submit()">
</form>
```

However, the page just keeps automatically submitting the form, I'm suspecting that It has something to do with the $(document).ready(function() part but, my skills with jquery are very limited and can't figure out a way to stop this from happening.

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this code which seems to work, is this the best way to do this?

```
$(function () {
$("#filter_category").live("change keyup", function () {
    $("#filter_form").submit();
});
});
```